# Excel Connector missing from Excel 2013 Add-in ribbon. How do I fix it?

Tags: excel

I downloaded the toolkit 4.0 and excel connector 1603, followed the instructions to add this in Options/Add-Ins. It's shown as an active application Add-ins, but it doesn't show up on the Add-ins ribbon. Does anyone know what's wrong and how to fix it? I have Excel 2013 running on Windows 8.

Thanks!

Comment: Does http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-load-excel-2013-addins.html help??

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old post, but I came to it seeking the same answer, and was unable to find anything else out via searching.  In order to access the Excel Connector in Excel 2013, install everything as normal (Download the Force.com ToolKit and install, download the proper version of the excel connector, and install via the add-ons within Excel).  After this, go to the downloaded excel connector file and open it directly.  This will prompt the Macro Security check that does not get prompted during the standard installation process with 2013 (but does with 2010 and 2007).  Once security is authorized, close the program, and re-open Excel as normal.  The connector will now be available in the Add-Ons tab just as previous versions of Excel.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Connecter only works for 2007. There is a pilot for Excel 2010 [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Salesforce_Reports_for_Excel_%28Pilot%29).

Apparently, people have been able to do a work around for 2013. There are some comments on it [here](http://www.app-x.com/salesforce-connector-for-office-workaround/).

Hope this helps